# How can I show specific messages in logs as bars in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

I would like to show each bar in Kibana bar chart from a specific message from my application.

Bars should be flowing from right to left.

There shouldn't be more than 15 bars in the bar chart.

Specifically, each microservice in my app will have its name logged in the log file, when it's being requested or responding to a request it will have a footprint in the log as its name, I just want to represent the same.

The things I have already tried:

1. Split series ... other messages including errors are also being tracked and appear as bars.
2. Filters  ... it is showing total bars showing the total count of occurrences of microservices

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please show some code in order to be able to help you solve your issue

Comment: Hi @Franck Gamess Thanks for reply, i am not writing any code... its the visualisation part of the application logs using Kibana.

Comment: @FranckGamess Thanks for improving my question... its more readable now. i will try to follow the same next time.

Comment: I am not skilled enough with ELK suite (elasticsearch-kibana-logstash) to be able to help you but I think someone will come into this topic and bring a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your logs field is text (i.e. type: text)
create new bar chart visualisation
buckets - x-axis, filters

In the filter box e.g.: 
  my_logs_field: "my_microservice1 used"
or whatever query is appropriate
add label
my_microservice1

add label
and repeat for all microservices

The problem with this solution is you will need to know what microservices you have, and update accordingly.
You could have a bar for when none of those microservices are picked up with the filter:
  NOT my_logs_field: "my_microservice1 used" NOT my_logs_field: "my_microservice2 used" NOT my_logs_field: "my_microservice3 used"
etc.

based off ELK v6.3.2